# Repairing system partition of Yuphoria

Tags: rom-flashing, unbricking, system, partitions, micromax-yu-yuphoria

My Yuphoria is currently hardbricked and whenever I try to flash its factory image, it gives up during the flashing of the system image, saying remote: flash write failure. The reason seems to be corrupt system partition. How can I repair it?

Answer (score 1):

**Try With This Method:**

Flash With This Firmware

Flash-Tool : [QPST.WIN.2.7_Installer-00430.1.rar](http://mtk-p.micromaxinfo.com/product/YU5010A/HW%20V1.0/Tools/QPST.WIN.2.7_Installer-00430.1.rar)

Firmware : [SW_T86519A1_V011_M21_MP_MMX_CM_YU5010_signed_qfil.rar](http://mtk-p.micromaxinfo.com/product/YU5010A/HW%20V1.0/Software/India/V2_121012/SW_T86519A1_V011_M21_MP_MMX_CM_YU5010_signed_qfil.rar)

Comment: How to resolve No Port in QFIL ?